# Intersection of row and column including if-else statement

Tags: vba, excel

So I am making a tolerance calculator for mechanical purposes. I created an Excel sheet with the specified tolerances. With this sheet Excel needs to check which column and which row the user inputs and than return the intersecting value.

[image: Tolerance sheet]

Now checking the column isn't much of a problem since it exists of hole numbers. However, for the rows Excel needs to check if the value is between the value of B and C and use that row to intersect with.

My question is if it's possible to use normal Excel formula or do I have to create a macro? Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you determining whether to return row 1 or 2 when the input value is between 1 and 3?

Comment: @C. Krepel where is the user going to input the values?  and like jacob said how do you determine row 1 or 2 or row 3 or 4? can you detail the process so that we can better help you? also what have tried? have you tried anything, code, formula , etc...

Comment: If the column titles were combined: `A-9`, `A-11`,... then a simple INDEX,MATCH,MATCH would do it in formula.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The user will input its value in another sheet which than passes it to the tolerance sheet and return the intersecting value. @ScottCraner I will try your method. Though the user can also input a decimal value. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use CHOOSE to select columns D:E, F:H or I:K depending on a, b or c.

```
=INDEX(CHOOSE(MATCH(B2, {"a","b","c"}, 0), D6:E9, F6:H9, I6:K9), MATCH(A2, B6:B9, 1), MATCH(C2, CHOOSE(MATCH(B2, {"a","b","c"}, 0), D5:E5, F5:H5, I5:K5), 1))
```

[image]

The terminating nominal sizes in column C are wholly irrelevant.

Comment: Hmm, this one might actually solve the problem without having any macro's. I'll let you know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the worksheet change event, to see when a user has made a change.  The code below will start you off, and give you the general idea, it needs to go in the relevant sheet module, ie "Sheet1" in the VB editor:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "Value: " & Target.Value
    Debug.Print "Row: " & Target.Row
    Debug.Print "Col: " & Target.Column
    Debug.Print "Col Header y: " & Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value
    Debug.Print "Row Header x: " & Cells(1, Target.Row).Value
End Sub
```

You will need to use these values to decide if the user value is correct.  You'll need to update the values of 1 for the row and columns with headers.  You can then use simple operators to compare them

Comment: I will try out your method. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @C.Krepel any time, try to write up the code to fit your situation a bit more and come back with questions if it doesn't work.  good luck